# How to assign the integer to pointer data?

Tags: c, casting

I'm not familiar with C language. I'm studying it.

I've got a function as looks like this.
I'm keep trying to do to assign integer data to uint8_t *data but it does not.
I've got a error 0x00 does not match to uint8_t *data.
how do I assign to my integer(0x00) data to there?

```
sccb_write_reg(0x01, 0x00); //<---it makes error


void sccb_write_reg(uint16_t reg, uint8_t *data)
{
...
...
}
```

Would you please let me know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this particular case, the context clues tell us there should be `data` in the calling function and you should pass its address in:

```
uint8_t data = 0x00;
uin16_t reg = 0x01;
sccb_write_reg(reg, &data);
```

Note the ampersand (`&`) before the `data`. That says, "Pass in the address of `data`" which is what a `uint8_t *` is, it's a memory address.

Answer (score 2):

```
uint8_t parameter = 0x00;
sccb_write_reg(0x01, &parameter);
```